# Express.js redirect() does not appear to work

Tags: javascript, express

More precisely, it appears to work only for one route.

Here is the (relevant) server-side code:

```
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.render("about.ejs", { commentDB: commentDB });
});

//redirect() works here
app.post("/about", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let { handle, satisfaction, comment } = req.body;
    commentDB.push({ "user": handle, "satisfaction": satisfaction, "comment": comment, "id": uuidv4() });
    res.redirect("/about");
});

//issue!
app.patch("/about/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { id } = req.params,
        newComment = req.body.newComment,
        oldComment = commentDB.find(c => c.id === id);
    oldComment.comment = newComment;
    res.redirect(303, "/about");
});
```

And for my Javascript which uses Axios:

```
async function patchReq(commentLink, val) {
    try {
        await axios.patch(commentLink, { "newComment": val }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

I verified with my console that I do receive correct data from app.patch("/about/:id") and my comments are indeed updating once I refresh the page. `res.redirect()` just simply does not work. I have tried using `render()` and changing the method to POST only to no avail. I do not get any error messages from the console.

Comment: Oh so many duplicates. Redirect means "Get what you want from this URL instead" not "Navigate the main browser viewport to this URL". You're making an Ajax request. The response is handled by the JavaScript you haven't written, not by the browser navigating.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I couldn't find the similar questions.